# How to make a Visual Basics application that forces a bluescreen

Tags: vb.net, bsod

I'm developing a program in Visual Studio right now, but I want to be able to make a button that forces a blue screen on a windows machine. I know that there is a way to force one by make a CrashOnCtrlScroll key in regedit. But the requires a restart and for the application to be run again. I just want it to be instant or close to. Thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blue screen appears only for kernel-mode errors. Code that runs in user-mode (such as a Visual Basic application) is not going to generate a blue screen. It can never *directly* generate a system crash.

The only way to do this is to install a kernel-mode driver that can force the blue screen, which you then invoke *indirectly* from your user-mode code. You mentioned one way: [configuring the keyboard driver to initiate a system crash under certain conditions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff545499.aspx). Another option is to create a kernel-mode driver of your own that calls the [`KeBugCheckEx` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551961.aspx) (or equivalent), and then invoke this functionality from your VB application. For example, Mark Russinovich has written a little utility, [NotMyFault](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) (download [here](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/NotMyFault.zip)), that uses a helper kernel mode driver to force a crash condition.

A final option is to destabilize the operating system. I believe a simple way to do this is by forcibly killing the process "csrss.exe". Last time I checked, this caused a BSOD. Obviously this requires administrative privileges. And I'm not sure if there are checks in place within the OS itself now that *prevent* this process from being killed; it is very likely. And if you are allowed to destroy the state of the machine permanently, you have a number of fun options: for example, trashing the HKLM key in the system registry.

That said, dare I inquire as to the ***utility*** of such a "feature"? Would you and/or your users be content just installing the [Blue Screen of Death Screen Saver](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897558.aspx)?